# PHP font height function is not working

Tags: php

I tried executing the following php code but it always returns 1.How do I fix this?

```
    <?php
    $font_size = 4;
    $height = imagefontheight($font_size);
    echo $height;
    ?>
```

Comment: imagefontheight requires a font, not a font size: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefontheight.php. The numbers that you can use are referring to built in fonts.

Comment: When I ran your exact code [here](http://phpfiddle.org/) it returned 16.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to understand how [imagefontheight](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefontheight.php) function works.

**Signature of function**

```
int imagefontheight ( int $font )
```

**Built in fonts**

Can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for built-in fonts in latin2 encoding (where higher numbers corresponding to larger fonts).

Font map looks like:

```
Font height: 8 for inner font 1
Font height: 13 for inner font 2
Font height: 13 for inner font 3
Font height: 16 for inner font 4
Font height: 15 for inner font 5
```

**External fonts**

You can also find height of external font using imagefontheight() together with imageloadfont().

```
// Load a .gdf font
$font = imageloadfont('anonymous.gdf');
echo 'Font height: ' . imagefontheight($font);
```

**What your code actually doing?**

```
$font_size = 4;
$height = imagefontheight($font_size);
echo $height;
```

You take inner font with number `4` and getting height for it. Which is equals to `16`. This value can change in another environment, but code will always return constant number.